# Integration applying of laws

Tags: calculus, integration

Give that

$$\int_4^7 f(x) dx = 8 $$

Evaluate

$$\int_4^6 f(x) dx - \int_7^6 (f(x) + 3x) dx $$

I just did the simple thing of pulling them out together but I got stuck afterwards ...

$$\int_4^6 f(x) dx - \int_7^6 f(x) dx- \int_7^6 3x dx $$

From here and the given information, I'm totally clueless on how to carry on.. any hints will be appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

$$\int_a^b f(x) dx = -\int_b^a f(x) dx$$

$$\int_a^b f(x) dx + \int_b^c f(x) dx = \int_a^c f(x) dx$$